# Nancy accessing/rewriting response

Tags: c#, nancy

I'm attempting to inject some text (specifically a few lines of javascript code), into the HTML response from Nancy after it's found the view and processed everything. The `After` hook seems to be where I want to be doing this. I can access the `Response` object through the context I'm given, but my attempts to retrieve any data from it fails. It is of type `Action<Stream>` so I've been trying to get it written into memory, then a string as follows:

```
public HelloModule()
{
    After += ctx => {
                var stream = new MemoryStream();
                ctx.Response.Contents.Invoke(stream);

                stream.Position = 0;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
    };

    Get["/"] = p => View["Issues/Views/SingleIssue"];            
}
```

But, when this runs I get an exception on the line `ctx.Response.Contents(stream);`. The exception is an `InvalidOperationException` which only states that `"CSRF is not enabled on this request"`.

So, my question is: How do I get Nancy to allow me access to the HTML of the current `Response` its produced? Or am I completely off with how I'm trying to do this? Is there a better way?

**Edit 2:** This appears to be an issue with the *SuperSimpleViewEngine*. I just created a new, clean project with a single view. SSVE can reproduce it, but the spark view engine will work just fine.

**Edit 1:**

As requested some more information. The code above now contains the entire constructor for the module. I have no custom bootstrapper or other logic in the way. The view is a rather simple view using the default *SuperSimpleViewEngine*, it's composed exactly as follows:

**Master.sshtml**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.22.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/dais-exts.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/Style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" />
    @Section['Head']
</head>
<body>
    @Section['Content']
</body>
</html>
```

**SingleIssue.sshtml**

```
@Section['Head']
    <title>Hello!</title>
@EndSection

@Section['Content']
    <h2>View/Edit Issue</h2>

    <form id="issue-form" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="HttpMethod" value="Put" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
@EndSection
```

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more context (i.e what kind of view are your rendering, what does it look like, have you done anything custom in the bootstrapper and so on)? It works fine reading a basic razor view https://gist.github.com/3205877

Comment: CSRF is the anti-forgery token stuff, so have you enabled that and is using that from your view?

Comment: Updated the question. I've not knowingly enabled or used any of that, unless it's there by default?

Comment: I can confirm that I am also able to reproduce this if I change it to a SuperSimpleViewEngine view. Going to investigate!

Comment: Right. SSVE always assumes CSRF is enabled, which it normally is but since the rendering of the view is now happening in a different order, the token has not been generated. Will look into a work around / fix

Comment: I see, that does make some amount of sense. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: We have a fix in place, which will be pushed to our master branch shortly, but unfortunately there is no other work around then the code update

Comment: The fix has been applied. Unfortunately it won't be released until we release 0.12 (soon) unless you build from source. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: That's not a problem - thank you very much for your help, and speedy resolution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering the question, just so anyone finding this knows what's going on.

This is actually a bug in Nancy (version 0.11) and only occurs when using the SuperSimpleViewEngine. Unfortunately there's no easy workarounds or solutions, but a fix has been applied to the source. So, the options to resolve the issue are:

- Wait for Nancy 0.12.
- Build a new version yourself from [source](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/).
- Use a different view engine.